# Check php minify for failures

Tags: php, javascript, minify

What's the best way to discover whether a php minify script (minify.php or jsmin.php) is failing, and console.warn() that if the browser supports? Ideally, the warning would tell the developer which file caused the failure in the minify script.

What we're seeing is a more or less silent failure, where the minify script tries to minify an already-minified file, and returns that file up to the point of failure, and any files before, but nothing after. There are no errors. So a front-end dev might have no idea what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would turn on error reporting and set it on `E_ALL` then I would set `LogLevel debug` in apache's site configuration and check its error log

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately server-side debugging is the only way to catch it.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the resulting script either works, or is completely broken, thus you will either get a working script, or a bunch of heavy errors in *every* browser (including a not working script).